# Column Concatenation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, string-concatenation

I'm trying to Concatenate these three columns into one but having the error, any help?

```
 WITH ABC AS
    (select tsk.task_number || ' / '|| tsk.task_status|| ' / '|| tsk.summary,
            CSI.creation_date AS creation_date
    FROM csf_ct_task_assignments tsa,CSF_DEBRIEF_HEADERS db, csf_ct_tasks tsk ,CSI_ITEM_INSTANCES csi
    where 1=1
    and tsk.customer_product_id = csi.instance_id 
    and tsk.INCIDENT_CUSTOMER_ID = csi.OWNER_PARTY_ID
    and tsa.Task_Assignment_Id=db.Task_Assignment_Id(+)
    and tsk.task_id = tsa.task_id (+)
    and tsk.task_type like '%Termination%'
    and tsk.task_status_id<>7
    and (SELECT  actual_shipment_date
    FROM oe_order_lines_all
    WHERE line_id= csi.last_oe_order_line_id)
    <= tsk.creation_date
    and rownum=1
    ) AS termination_call_dtls,
```

**[Error] :** `Execution (14: 74): ORA-00936: missing expression`

Comment: The WITH clause syntax is `with abc as ( ... ) select * from abc;`. So Oracle is expecting SELECT after the right parenthesis but you have given it `AS termination_call_dtls,` instead.

Comment: and you urgently need to get rid of old syntax of SQL with comma-seperated tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i want to concatenate those columns in termination_call_dtls!!

The problem, as @APC mentioned, is that you're trying to alias the `WITH` block. It isn't clear that you need subquery factoring at all here; you can just do:

```
select tsk.task_number || ' / '|| tsk.task_status|| ' / '|| tsk.summary AS termination_call_dtls,
  CSI.creation_date AS creation_date
FROM csf_ct_task_assignments tsa,CSF_DEBRIEF_HEADERS db, csf_ct_tasks tsk ,CSI_ITEM_INSTANCES csi
where 1=1
and tsk.customer_product_id = csi.instance_id 
and tsk.INCIDENT_CUSTOMER_ID = csi.OWNER_PARTY_ID
and tsa.Task_Assignment_Id=db.Task_Assignment_Id(+)
and tsk.task_id = tsa.task_id (+)
and tsk.task_type like '%Termination%'
and tsk.task_status_id<>7
and (SELECT  actual_shipment_date
FROM oe_order_lines_all
WHERE line_id= csi.last_oe_order_line_id)
<= tsk.creation_date
and rownum=1
```

with `termination_call_dtls` as a *column* alias on the first line.

As also mentioned in comments you should consider using modern join syntax instead of the old and Oracle-only syntax you have now; and the subquery might be better as another join, something like:

```
select tsk.task_number || ' / '|| tsk.task_status|| ' / '|| tsk.summary as termination_call_dtls,
  csi.creation_date
from csf_ct_tasks tsk
join csi_item_instances csi on csi.instance_id = tsk.customer_product_id
and csi.owner_party_id = tsk.incident_customer_id
join oe_order_lines_all oola on oola.line_id = csi.last_oe_order_line_id
and ools.actual_shipment_date <= tsk.creation_date
left join csf_ct_task_assignments tsa on tsa.task_id = tsk.task_id
left join csf_debrief_headers db on db.task_assignment_id = tsa.task_assignment_id
where tsk.task_type like '%Termination%'
and tsk.task_status_id != 7
and rownum = 1
```

Either way you can still use the query as a CTE if you need to - if it's part of a larger and more complicated query than you showed.

It isn't clear why you have the (outer) joins to `csf_ct_task_assignments` or `csf_debrief_headers`, since you don't use any columns from those tables anyway. Those joins can probably just be removed.

You should also be aware that `and rownum = 1` is going to give you an indeterminate row back, assuming you get multiple rows without it. Normally you would have an inline view that includes an `order by` clause, and then apply the `rownum` filter afterwards to limit the results, e.g. (guessing that you want the earliest creation date):

```
select termination_call_dtls, creation_date
from (
  select tsk.task_number || ' / '|| tsk.task_status|| ' / '|| tsk.summary as termination_call_dtls,
    csi.creation_date
  from csf_ct_tasks tsk
  join csi_item_instances csi on csi.instance_id = tsk.customer_product_id
  and csi.owner_party_id = tsk.incident_customer_id
  join oe_order_lines_all oola on oola.line_id = csi.last_oe_order_line_id
  and ools.actual_shipment_date <= tsk.creation_date
  where tsk.task_type like '%Termination%'
  and tsk.task_status_id != 7
  order by csi.creation_date
)
where rownum = 1
```

From 12c there are other mechanisms to simplify that a bit. Or using aggregation:

```
select tsk.task_number || ' / '|| tsk.task_status|| ' / '|| tsk.summary as termination_call_dtls,
  min(csi.creation_date) as creation_date
from csf_ct_tasks tsk
join csi_item_instances csi on csi.instance_id = tsk.customer_product_id
and csi.owner_party_id = tsk.incident_customer_id
join oe_order_lines_all oola on oola.line_id = csi.last_oe_order_line_id
and ools.actual_shipment_date <= tsk.creation_date
where tsk.task_type like '%Termination%'
and tsk.task_status_id != 7
group by tsk.task_number, tsk.task_status, tsk.summary
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with concatenation in your query.

You need to use `WITH` along with `SELECT` as following:

```
WITH ABC AS (
    SELECT
        TSK.TASK_NUMBER
        || ' / '
        || TSK.TASK_STATUS
        || ' / '
        || TSK.SUMMARY as termination_call_dtls,
        CSI.CREATION_DATE   AS CREATION_DATE
    FROM
        CSF_CT_TASK_ASSIGNMENTS TSA,
        CSF_DEBRIEF_HEADERS DB,
        CSF_CT_TASKS TSK,
        CSI_ITEM_INSTANCES CSI
    WHERE
        1 = 1
        AND TSK.CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID = CSI.INSTANCE_ID
        AND TSK.INCIDENT_CUSTOMER_ID = CSI.OWNER_PARTY_ID
        AND TSA.TASK_ASSIGNMENT_ID = DB.TASK_ASSIGNMENT_ID (+)
        AND TSK.TASK_ID = TSA.TASK_ID (+)
        AND TSK.TASK_TYPE LIKE '%Termination%'
        AND TSK.TASK_STATUS_ID <> 7
        AND (
            SELECT
                ACTUAL_SHIPMENT_DATE
            FROM
                OE_ORDER_LINES_ALL
            WHERE
                LINE_ID = CSI.LAST_OE_ORDER_LINE_ID
        ) <= TSK.CREATION_DATE
        AND ROWNUM = 1
)
-- YOU ARE MISSING FOLLOWING SELECT STATEMENT
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ABC;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: but i want to concatenate  those columns in  termination_call_dtls!!

Comment: So you are bother about name of the column then see my updated answer